# Get notifcation when add new data to firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android

when open the application i want to get notification if new data added to firebase realtime database  .
but whan i open the app i got notifcation every time i open the it.
what should i do
this is my code.

```
    cam_firebase.child("Detection").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                double longt = dataSnapshot.child("longt").getValue(Double.class);
                double lat = dataSnapshot.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
                notify_me();
              
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

            }


        });
```